# How to get a related object?

Tags: php, twig, ezpublish

I have a class `list_article` with an attribute of type `Relation Objects` to retrieve article objects. What is the simplest way to get this related object in a Twig template?

Comment: `Twig` is used for output, i suggest your write a getter in your model and just do `{% for object in foo.getRelatedObjects() %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, you can't. The best you can do in Twig is to retreive the list of related content IDs with `ez_field_value(content, 'my_relation_field').destinationContentIds`.

To fetch the content objects themselves, your best bet would be to use a subrequest to execute a controller which loads the related content and then renders it in a separate Twig template.